# Issue with RedirectAttributes on SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm having an issue with RedirectAttributes not saving (i think). This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/job_offers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createJobOffer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("jobOfferForm") JobOfferForm jobOfferForm,
            final BindingResult binding, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.jobOfferForm", binding);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("jobOfferForm", jobOfferForm);

        return "redirect:/job_offers";
    }

@RequestMapping(path = "/job_offers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView jobOffers(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "skill_id") final Long skillId,
            @ModelAttribute("jobOfferForm") JobOfferForm jobOfferForm, final BindingResult binding) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("job_offers/index");

        mav.addAllObjects(getJobOffersMap(skillId));
        mav.addObject("jobOfferForm", jobOfferForm);

        return mav;
    }
```

If I print my binding in the POST method it has the error in it, but when I call the GET method via the redirect the binding comes empty! and Spring doesnt show the error feedback on forms because of that

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 In your POST

```
 attr.addFlashAttribute("bindignResultForJobOfferForm", binding);
```

And in GET

```
if (model.asMap().containsKey("bindignResultForJobOfferForm"))
    {
        model.addAttribute("errors",
                model.asMap().get("bindignResultForJobOfferForm"));
    }
```

Comment: I've tried an approach somewhat like this and it worked. But the issue is that  the binding is used by Spring to show the errors in forms (like "password too short", etc ). It's not just a random variable.

Edit: I've realized you might have seen it that way because of the comment, that was a testing thing, my bad! I've removed it

Comment: ok. one question. In the signature of get method why do you need the form as a model attribute?! ... i think that, that's what make the messages dissapear

Comment: @ModelAttribute can be used as the method arguments / parameter or before the method declaration. The primary objective of this annotation is to bind the request parameters or form fields to an model object.

Ref: http://www.javabeat.net/modelattribute-spring-mvc/

.   By passing that field the form doesnt clear when you have some error ( the post gets the form instance, and the get fills it again with the previous data)